# Множественное наследование и зависимости в Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, наследование, интерфейс, зависимости

Прошу совет.

```kotlin
/** Kotlin */

interface IBase

interface I1 : IBase
interface I2 : IBase

class C1 : IBase, I1, I2
```

Как видно, от интерфейса `IBasе` наследуются оба интерфейса и класс. Если я уберу `IBase` из предков класса `C1`, то ничего не изменится, т.к. через цепочку зависимостей (`IBase` -> `I1` или `I2` -> `C1`) класс все равно получит доступ к методам `IBase`. Но я не хотел бы этого делать.

Чем плох такой подход? Если он плох, то как скорректировать код?

Comment: А что это вам дает? Ведь в любом случае `C1() is IBase` будет `true`. Такой подход плох только тем, что он абсолютно избыточен.

Comment: В Kotlin **нету** множественного наследования. Класс может реализовывать несколько интерфейсов, но не может наследоваться от нескольких базовых классов.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, вы правы. Именно избыточность мне не нравится тут. Вы предлагаете все-таки убрать `IBase` из предков `C1`?

Comment: @zed, спасибо, вы правы. Я написал так, как написал, чтобы сократить заголовок. Возможно, что это было зря.

Comment: Избыточен значит бесполезен, не несет полезной информации. Но если вам это дает какой-то смысл, оставляйте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам остается только спроектировать эту иерархию наследования так, чтобы `I1` и `I2` не наследовались от `IBase`.

Избежать при реализации интерфейса реализацию всех его суперинтерфейсов нельзя.